# list.sort fails with abort when list is created with stateful allocator when compiled with gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Code below runs fine when compiled with VC compiler, but fail with `abort` inside `list.sort` on Linux when compiled with gcc (any recent version like 7.5 to 10.2).

The reason why abort is called is because `splice` method used in `list.sort` compares 2 allocators (which is correct) and they don't match. One of them is what I pass into `list` constructor (with custom state), another is created by STL using default constructor.

My question - is this correct behavior of C++ library to use allocator's default constructor as opposed to using instance which I provide for item allocation or create it with copying constructor?

UPDATE: As T.C. mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716394/list-sort-fails-with-abort-when-list-is-created-with-stateful-allocator-when-com#comment112671426_63716394) this is known libstdc++ [bug 66742](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66742).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class my_allocator
{
public:
    using value_type = typename std::remove_const<T>::type;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using size_type = size_t;

    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef my_allocator<U> other;
    };

    my_allocator() : m_internalState(0)
    {
        cout << "my_allocator(): internal state=" << m_internalState << endl;
    }

    my_allocator(const void* pAllocator) : m_internalState(pAllocator)
    {
        cout << "my_allocator(const void * pAllocator): internal state=" << m_internalState << endl;
    }

    template <typename U>
    my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>& myAllocator) noexcept : m_internalState(myAllocator.m_internalState)
    {
        cout << "my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>& myAllocator): internal state=" << m_internalState << endl;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type count, const void* = nullptr)
    {
        return (pointer)malloc(sizeof(T) * count);
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type count = 0)
    {
        free(p);
    }

    bool operator==(const my_allocator& other) const
    {
        cout << "operator==(const my_allocator& other): this=" << m_internalState
            << ", other=" << other.m_internalState << endl;
        return m_internalState == other.m_internalState;
    }

    bool operator!=(const my_allocator& other) const
    {
        return !(this->operator==(other));
    }
private:
    template <typename U>
    friend class my_allocator;

    const void* m_internalState;
};

int main()
{
    // all asserts below are true
    //using X = my_allocator<int>;
    //using Y = my_allocator<long>;
    //Y b((void*)1);
    //X a(b);
    //assert(Y(a) == b);
    //assert(a == X(b));
    //assert(a == b);

    cout << "Create list" << endl;

    auto allocator = my_allocator<int>((void*)2);
    auto l2 = std::list<int, my_allocator<int>>(allocator);

    l2.emplace_back(2);
    l2.emplace_back(1);

    cout << "Sort list" << endl;
    l2.sort(); // Abort is called here

    cout << "Success" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C++ (vc++) output (as provided by running this code on https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

```
Create list
my_allocator(const void * pAllocator): internal state=0000000000000002
my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>& myAllocator): internal state=0000000000000002
Sort list
operator==(const my_allocator& other): this=0000000000000002, other=0000000000000002
Success
```

C++ (gcc) output

```
Error(s):

Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Create list
my_allocator(const void * pAllocator): internal state=0x2
my_allocator(const my_allocator<U>& myAllocator): internal state=0x2
Sort list
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
my_allocator(): internal state=0
operator==(const my_allocator& other): this=0, other=0x2
```

Stack trace when `abort` is called

```
>   std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::_M_check_equal_allocators(std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > * const this, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > & __x) Line 1829
    std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::splice(std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > * const this, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::const_iterator __position, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > & __x, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::const_iterator __i) Line 1480
    std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::splice(std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > * const this, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::const_iterator __position, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > & __x, std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::const_iterator __i) Line 1502
    std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> >::sort(std::__cxx11::list<int, my_allocator<int> > * const this) Line 481
    main() Line 90
```

Comment: Longstanding libstdc++ bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66742